# Define a bijection between $(A^B)^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given the following task

> Define a bijection between ${(A^B)}^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$

I have no clue where to start and I don't understand the task. Could you please explain what I am required to show and how should I start the proof ?

Comment: Ummm... what are $A$, $B$, and $C$?   Don't you think that matters?

Comment: This information was not given in the description of a task.

Answer (score 0):

For sets, $A^B$ represents the set of functions from $B$ to $A$.  That means $(A^B)^C$ is the set of functions from $C$ to (functions from $B$ to $A$).  $A^{B \times C}$ is the set of functions from $B \times C$ to $A$.  You are expected to describe a bijection between these sets.

Comment: Right, so to describe bijection, I have to show that $f$ is 1-1 and onto. Could you suggest how should I start?

Comment: Think of what the functions look like.  There is a very natural bijection between them.